# Second textbox doesn't show up like i want

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, oop

```
  //Sign up button Adjustments
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Second Password label and textbox for sign up
                label3.Visible = true;
                PassBox2.Visible = true;
            
                //Error message for username and password blank
                if (CheckBlank(UserBox.Text, PassBox1.Text) == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username and Password must not be blank", "Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            
            
            
                //Error message for username and password length
                else if (CheckLength(UserBox.Text, PassBox1.Text) == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username and Password must be at least 6 characters long", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            
            
            
                //Error message for password confirmation
                else if (CheckMatch(PassBox1.Text, PassBox2.Text) == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Passwords must match", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
               //attend new values from text boxes to variables
                else
                {
                    username = UserBox.Text;
                    password = PassBox1.Text;
                    password2 = PassBox2.Text;
                }
            //Adressing UserInfo.csv file 
            string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();


            //Error message for username already existing
            if (CheckUsername(username) == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username already exists", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            
            
            
                //Store the new user's username and hashed password in the UserInfo.csv file
                else
                {
                    StoreUserInfo(username, HashPassword(password));
                    MessageBox.Show("User created successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

            
            }
```

Hello guys this is my code i want second password textbox show up when i clicked sign up button then later check what is expected but when i click on sign up program directly store username and password
what should i do i can not over this problem

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you have an sign in form and you want to change to sign up form. Right? You want to just make visible the text box but same time you make the StoreUserInfo(...) process in click event. I just not understand why error not occurs on 'Passwords must match' or 'Username and Password must be at least 6 characters long'. If you can add a bit more explanation and share your util functions maybe we can help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: it is just one form but when i click i wanna show second password textbox and label but the program saves directly when all confirmation is true without showing seconds

Comment: reyiz zaten türkmüşsün eyv

Comment: You should include a snippet of your XAML where the elements are defined, as that could be the issue

Comment: @Narish XAML? question was tagged as winforms

Comment: @Cleptus you are right, sorry, didn't catch that and thought this was WPF. Point still stands, front end code will probably help find a resolution quicker, as all we see is the visibility set to true and a bunch of unrelated msg boxes

Comment: This forum only supports English Q&A. Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in comment your code make textbox visible and after that all sign up process continues. You need to separate this two action. Your code have to handle two different situations. I am giving a basic example below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (PassBox2.Visible)
    {
        // Process save here with all controls
    }
    else 
    {
        // Just make visible your textbox
        label3.Visible = true;
        PassBox2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

In addition to this as you can see while save action your code not throwing an error, The reason of this is if blocks. You need to check and reorganize your  if blocks (controls).

Comment: Eyv kral sağolasın esogü power